# Openlayers 4 - Determine if layer is a layer group

Tags: openlayers

Is there a method or property in javascript using the Openlayers (3 or) 4 library which I can use to verify if a given layer is a layer group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test your layer to see if it's an instance of a layer group:

```
if (myLayer instanceof ol.layer.Group) {
    alert("It's a group!");
}
```

Comment: spot on.  i had found this a short while ago.  UPVOTED and CHOSEN.  : )
PS next question: how to get child layers in group?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/248533/8038

Answer (score 0):

Check out this leaflet plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet.markercluster.layersupport

checkIn() methods may return added layer groups.

Comment: i'd have to use leaflet instead of the OL library, right?